# How to imitate ActiveRecord .includes() return set, by using joins.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I want a return set something of this in nature

```
A
.select('a.id, a.name, b.date, SUM(b.amount)')
.includes(:b)
.group('a.id, b.date")
```

however .includes() simply ignores the .select(). I generate an almost identical query using something like this. (but with my selected items)

```
A
.select('a.id, a.name, b.date, SUM(b.amount)')
.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON a.b_id = b.id')
.group('a.id, b.date")
```

However, the problem is that Rails doesn't know what to do with the `B` attributes. It doesn't structure the nested result set like .includes().

**Question:** Is it possible to get a return set structured like .includes, but using .joins('LEFT JOINS').

I've been exploring ideas, which includes iterating through the return set manually, and mocking `A.new()`, and `B.new()` and creating the nested result I'm looking for.

Comment: This page may be of help.

http://blog.bigbinary.com/2013/07/01/preload-vs-eager-load-vs-joins-vs-includes.html

Answer (score 0):

Andrew,

Can you try below piece of code and see if it works

```
A
.joins(:b)
.select('a.id, a.name, b.date, SUM(b.amount)')
.group('a.id, b.date")
```